# jquery enter date in one field and autocomplete another field with weekday

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have a form with 2 fields:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" name="dateeffective" />
<input type="text" name="weekday" id="weekday" />
```

I would like to autocomplete the "weekday" field  (i.e. monday) after entering the date on the "dateeffective" field (i.e 2016-01-25).

I guess it's done with jQuery...

**SOLUTION**: 
 for anybody who has same goal, code is here https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#alt-field

```
 $(function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
    altField: "#weekday",
    altFormat: "DD"
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think the best way is to go with jQuery. Something like:

```
var date = $('.datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
var dayIndex= date.getUTCDay();

var weekday = new Array(7);
weekday[0]=  "Sunday";
weekday[1] = "Monday";
weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
weekday[4] = "Thursday";
weekday[5] = "Friday";
weekday[6] = "Saturday";

var day = weekday[dayIndex];
```

Comment: Thanks, I I've entered your code righ after my datepicker `function $(function() { $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }); });`, but now the datepicker and the week day both don't work... Is there something else I should add, sorry, I'm not familiar with javascript